# How can I create parameterized Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-scriptler

I want to use same job in different machine. But I don't want to change the configuration of the job each time. Can I pass the machine name label as  parameter and run the job in different machine ? (Not simultaneously).

I want to pass parameters while running a job to the script which I have written in th configuration (batch script). Can we do that ?

Can I get a return value from a job and use it in next job?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Yes, you can pass a node label parameter with [NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin).
2. Yes, you can define parameters, as described, in [Parameterized Builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) and then use it in your script as an environment variable:

> The parameter is available as environment parameters. So e.g. a shell ($FOO, %FOO%) or Ant ( ${env.FOO} ) can access these values.

3. This is not exactly a return value, but you can pass any parameter (with its value) to the downstream job with [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).

Comment: Can't I use windows batch script and pass parameters ? It talks about shell script and ant

Comment: Please help me with instruction to us parameter to a windows batch script .

Comment: I got it!! Using %param% in the script!! :)

Answer (score 10):

```
Example criteria:
User needs to use different environments for executions.

1. Select jenkins project
2. Job -> Configure -> Select this project is parameterized check box.
3. Select Add parameter drop down - > String parameter
4. Define a string parameter (In my example I use environment variable as : BaseURL)
```

[image]

```
5.Now under build section initialize the mvn command user needs to execute.Here in this case I want to execute my jenkins build on a environment where I specify. So I should be able to execute my build in different environment each time with out changing the code.

My mvn command: I pass my environment url as a parameter (Using $ sign). This is based on user requirement. 
clean test -Dcustomproperty="$BaseURL"
```

[image]

```
6. Apply and save your Jenkins project.
7. Now your project is parameterized.  Then your project should have Build with parameters option.
```

[image]

```
8.Click Build with parameters link and enter your parameter (In this example my environment variable) and click build. Your jenkins job should run with the parameter.
```

[image]

```
NOTE: This build won't succeed unless the passing parameter is not utilized in the automation script. So script has to be modified to retrieve the passing variable.

String BaseURL= System.getProperty("customproperty");
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [parameterized Build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) and [NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin)