# User Interactive shell script not running in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a user interactive shell script that runs successfully on my Linux server. But when I try to run it via jenkins, it doesn't run.

I have created a Jenkinsfile.

**Jenkinsfile**

```
node('slaves')  {
      try
      {
    def app

stage('Remmove Docker service') {

        sh 'sshpass ssh docusr@10.26.13.12 "/path/to/shell/script"'

    }
}
}
```

**Shell Script**

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Hi kindly enter the api name : " api
docker service logs $api --raw
```

The shell Scipt runs successfully on my local server, when I try to run it on Jenkins using Jenkinsfile, it doesn't accept `$api` variable in my shell script which is user interactive.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve doesn't serve any purpose of automating your job by jenkins, if I correctly understood. So, your job is actually seeking a user input and it's in best interest to have a [parameterized jenkins build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51984034/1374644) in this case.
For your case, you can still give an argument to the sshpass command `$api` and have it read from the jenkins environment itself Or, better make your jenkins [build parameterized](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) and use your user input `$api` as the parameter.